# Is there a way to stop a magento indexer process?

Tags: magento

I've searched similar topics but no solution seems to work. Is there a way to stop a specific magento indexer process?

When I try to reindex from shell I get this:

```
php -f indexer.php reindex all
Stock Status Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
Product Prices Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
Catalog URL Rewrites Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
Product Flat Data Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
Category Flat Data Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
Category Products Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
Catalog Search Index Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
Tag Aggregation Data Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.
```

When I try to see indexer status I get this:

```
Product Attributes:            Pending
Product Prices:                Pending
Catalog URL Rewrites:          Pending
Product Flat Data:             Pending
Category Flat Data:            Pending
Category Products:             Pending
Catalog Search Index:          Pending
Stock Status:                  Pending
Tag Aggregation Data:          Pending
```

If I reindex from the admin, reindexing process throws no errors. Is there a link to some documentation on this matter?

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indexing mostly (mostly meaning I'm pretty sure it's always) happens during a single HTTP request.  If that request stop/timeouts/fails because of a PHP error, the indexer leaves lock files lying around even though there's no indexing going on.  These files are located in

```
/path/to/mage/var/locks/index_process*.lock
```

The

> Index process is working now. Please try run this process later

exception is Magento telling you it sees one of these lock files.  If you know for sure no one else is trying to run an index, just delete the files and restart your indexing.

Comment: I consult `top` and if it doesn't show an lsphp5 session (LiteSpeed WS) clocking out at a fairly high rate and quite continuously, then I know that no index process is actually running. The next step is to delete the lock files and run via command line separately each reindex to make sure that all run to completion by avoiding resource exhaustion and prematurely failed sessions. It pays to `top` during various Magento operations so you know what's normal processor usage, then this becomes an easy diagnosis.

Comment: Alan if you can please put some light on indexing process of magento.I started an indexing process (catalog search index) and it got stopped by closing browser. now ideally it should also terminate php process behind it but when i check mysql processlist ouptut it was suggesting that magento is still indexing in background the indexing was still running in background got confirmed when i saw that solr document were also updating. i didnt understand how magento manage to keep process running.the site is on staging so nobody else were initiating index either from shell or browser.

Comment: There is **NO** locks folder  in this path `/path/to/mage/var/`

Answer (score 5):

First, try to set the index mode to manual:

```
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalog_url
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalog_category_product
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --mode-manual cataloginventory_stock
php indexer.php --mode-manual tag_summary
```

Then, try to reindex all indexes:

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

And set the mode to realtime again:

```
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_url
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_category_product
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --mode-realtime cataloginventory_stock
php indexer.php --mode-realtime tag_summary
```

If this does not work, try to restart apache with something like `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. This should stop the indexing process and you can probably start it again afterwards. But mind that your site will not be available for a few seconds if you restart Apache.

Comment: Restarting Apache didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions the lock files has been changed and working from database(Magento 1.9).

Login to your phpMyAdmin, and run the below command.

```
UPDATE index_process SET status = 'pending' WHERE status = 'working'
```

Comment: This is not sufficient: have you done anything else to release that index status?

Comment: @nicolallias It's a long time back, I think  we need to clear the index_* tables as well to perform a complete rotate

Comment: I eventually did the same https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289455/advice-about-index-stuck/289503#289503