# Magento re-indexing troubles, product not showing after successful CLI re-index

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am running Magento 1.8.1, with just under 21,000 products

I have the [MIRASVIT `Fast Asynchronous Re-indexing`](http://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-asynchronous-reindex.html) module

I am getting the following notice: 
`One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Product Attributes, Product Prices, Catalog URL Rewrites, Category Products, Catalog Search Index, Stock Status, Tag Aggregation Data. Click here to go to Index Management and rebuild required indexes.`

Re-indexing from the back end takes several hours, understood with so many products
I have tried deleting the lock files and beginning the process again

I have also tried re-indexing from the CLI

```
indexer.php --status

Product Attributes:                 Pending
Product Prices:                     Pending
Catalog URL Rewrites:               Pending
Category Flat Data:                 Pending
Category Products:                  Pending
Catalog Search Index:               Pending
Stock Status:                       Pending
Tag Aggregation Data:               Pending


php indexer.php --reindexall

Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully
Category Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully
```

The fact that the "status" says "Pending" instead of "Require Reindex" is confusing, since the site is telling me that it still requires the reindex and products that have been added are not showing up on the site

Comment: try clear a cache from backend and files in cache folder also

Comment: I have cleared both server cache and Magento cache

Comment: In regards to the `Pending` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924756/is-there-a-way-to-stop-a-magento-indexer-process?rq=1

Comment: Did you set the correct permission of all magento files?